# How to concatenate two arbitrary long hex values?

Tags: python, hex, concatenation

I have two variables.
Variable A contains 1024 bytes (not always ascii characters, arbitrary hex values)
Variable B contains 64 bytes (not always ascii characters, arbitrary hex values)

How can I generate a variable C such that C = A || B ? (|| means concatenation)

Comment: Can you please show the sample of `A` and `B`?

Comment: What's wrong with just A + B?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `+` operator works on [bytes](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/stdtypes.html#bytes) too:

```
>>> b'\x12\x14' + b'\x16\x0b'
b'\x12\x14\x16\x0b'
```

Answer (score 0):

ummmm

```
A = '\x04\x05\x06'
B = '\x04\x05\x06'

C = A + B
```